# Increment excel value if range of cells contains "active"

Tags: excel

I've worked with excel formulas for a while now and can't quite figure out where my logic is flawed.

My goal is to increment a specific cell by 1 every time a range of cells contains the word "Active"

I thought I could do this by using the command: `"=SUM(IF(B2:B50="Active",1,0))"`

[image]

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: If you need the same range in each cell use $ to fix the range when you drag the formula down =SUM(IF($B$2:$B$50="Active",1,0)) and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B50,"Active")
```